# Signed measure vs. finite signed measure

Tags: measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $(X,\Sigma)$ a measurable space.

A function $\mu:\Sigma\to\mathbb R$ is called finite signed measure if it is $\sigma -$ additive.

A function $\lambda: \Sigma\to [-\infty,\infty] $ is called signed measure if

i) $\lambda(\emptyset)=0$

ii) $\lambda(\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda(A_n)$ where $A_1,A_2,\dots$ are disjoint sets in $\Sigma$.

iii) $\lambda$ may take only $\infty$ or $-\infty$ as values, but not both.

The definition I learned is the second. But in a lot of text books about measure theory signed measures are defined like the first definition. Why do they do so? I think proofs will be easier, but don't you lose a lot generality or is there a way to extend results from finite signed measures to signed measures?

Comment: You get a unified treatment with vector-valued measures as a result of using the first.  And to restrict to only one infinty feels rather ad hoc just because we want to retain $\infty$ as much as possible.

Comment: @user10354138 So do you say that $iii)$ is not really a necessary condition? Are there no examples where one really needs that the measure can take $\infinity$ as a value?

Comment: No, I'm saying in an attempt to retain some $\infty$'s you need to make the adhoc assumption that $\lambda$ doesn't take one of the $\pm\infty$ to avoid $\infty-\infty$.  But if you are prepared to remove one infinity then why not both so there isn't such a problem in the first place?  The intention to retain some $\infty$ is questionable philosophically and brings only minor benefits.

Comment: I meant with omitting $iii)$ that we then only consider finite signed measures. My knowledge is too limited to think of important problems where one really wants to consider signed measures that can take $+$ or $-$ $\infty$. Are there none?

Comment: @user10354138 Yes, saying it can't take both infinite values is ad hoc. In fact you don't have to assume this - a $\sigma$-additive $[-\infty,\infty]$-valued measure _cannot_ assume both values $\pm\infty$.

Comment: The first definition should imo be called just a "real measure".  People sometimes conflate real measures and signed measures, but that's wrong.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich does there arise any problems if one just consider real measures instead of signed measures, i.e. are there problems where one really needs that the  signed measure can take $\infty $ or $-\infty$?

Comment: So actually what  I want to understand why some authours use the first and other the second definition.

Comment: I really have no idea why anyone would care about signed measures (except for the special cases of positive measures and real  measures; of course it's clear why we want to allow $\infty$ as a value for a positive measure...)

Comment: so we can say in general, that it is no problem if  one only considers the definition of a finite signed measure aka real measure and does not care about signed measures that can take $\infty$ or $-\infty$